# Ruby regex with variable

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to have a regular expression that works with a variable in it

Right now it looks like `var=status.text[/.*#{keyword}.*is now available.*/io]`

but the variable breaks the regular expression

Comment: Could you provide more info, such as what "breaks" means?

Comment: it doesnt work when i use the variable but if instead if the code looks like var=status.text[/.*randomword.*is now available.*/io] it will work

Comment: is keyword assigned?  Is it from user input?  There may be a `\n` in the value... make sure the value of keyword is right

Comment: i did .chomp to get rid of the "/n" it still doesnt work though

Comment: i got it working thanks can i ask 1 more question sorry, i want to write a regular expression that will get the first url of any2 url's that are sepearted by a space ex: "http://www.google.com http://www.yahoo.com"

Comment: ^withh the http:// it cut it out in the comment

Comment: Please edit your question to explain the change you made to get your code working.  If you have another question, please post it as a new question.  In future, be more careful when stating your question, to make sure it is complete and precise.  Here it would have been helpful if gave example values for `status.text` and `keyword`, what you expected the associated output to be, and the exact error you got.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'breaks'?
It works out of the box

```
[36] pry(main)> a = 1
=> 1
[37] pry(main)> /#{a}/
=> /1/
```

Comment: it doesnt work when i put the variable in the regex

Comment: It does. What's your error message?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the variable in a string first, then convert the string to a regexp as follows:

```
[4] pry(main)> keyword = "cat"
=> "cat"
[5] pry(main)> my_regexp = Regexp.new(".*#{keyword}.*is now available.*")
=> /.*cat.*is now available.*/
```